# how can I find eclipse's specific launcher.Main class

Tags: eclipse

I need to specify launcer class of eclipse for ant build.

Here my-common.xml

```
<exec executable="${file.jvm.jdk1.7}" failonerror="false" timeout="180000000">
    <arg value="-Xms256m" />
    <arg value="-Xmx512m" />
    <arg value="-cp" />
    <arg value="${eclipse.startup.jar}" />
    <arg value="org.eclipse.HOW TO FIND HERE.Main" />
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found it at

Help>About Eclipse>Intallation Details>Configuration tab